# Display image in select option

Tags: html, angularjs

I have small image in my project and want to display it in select option.

```
<select>
  <option>random text</option>  -->There should be also an image
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only permitted contents for an `<option>` element is text.

```
Content categories: None.
Permitted content:  Text, possibly with escaped characters (like &eacute;).
Tag omission:       The start tag is mandatory. The end tag is optional if this element is immediately followed by another <option> element or an <optgroup>, or if the parent element has no more content.
Permitted parents:  A <select>, an <optgroup> or a <datalist> element.
Permitted ARIA roles:   None
DOM interface:      HTMLOptionElement
```

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Reference `<option>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)