# Add an extra button as option inside select tag so that on click on the button it opens another dialog

Tags: angularjs, select, button

I have a select dropdown which shows a list of names (using ng-repeat). If there are no names, I want to show a button 'Add Names' and on click on the button I want to perform some function.

I am using a normal select tag and using ng-repeat to show the list of names.

```
<select ng-model='selectedName' ng-change="onChange()">
    <option ng-repeat='name in names'>{{name}}</option>
    <option ng-if='!names.length'>
        <button ng-click="addName()">Add Name</button>
    </option>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.names = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

I expected that on click of the button it will call the addName() function but it is calling onChange() which is on select tag.

Answer (score 0):

The only permitted contents for an `<option>` element is text.<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55553312/5535245)</sup>

```
Content categories: None.
Permitted content:  Text, possibly with escaped characters (like &eacute;).
Tag omission:       The start tag is mandatory. The end tag is optional if this element is immediately followed by another <option> element or an <optgroup>, or if the parent element has no more content.
Permitted parents:  A <select>, an <optgroup> or a <datalist> element.
Permitted ARIA roles:   None
DOM interface:      HTMLOptionElement
```

For more information, see

- [MDN HTML Reference `<option>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Comment: Thank you for the response. But is there any other way so that i can perform ng-click operation. I cannot change the select tag.